# What does this mean: "This is Eva speaking"?

Tags: idioms

When a person answer a phone, *"This is Eva speaking"*, does this words mean one of the next? Or does it mean other way? When there are short words, it's not easy to imagine what the gaps would be in a foreign language 
[i] This situation is Eva speaking.
[ii] This one is Eva, who is calling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"This is Eva speaking" is a formal or polite way of identifying who is speaking on the phone. You might call a business and hear something like, "This is Frank speaking. How can I direct your call?" That means, "The person talking to you is named Frank. Who do you want to talk to?" But it is more polite, and you will probably only hear it from on a phone call with a business.

Also, this is sometimes shortened to "speaking" if you guess the name of the person. For example:

> Caller: "Hello, can I please speak to Keith?" 
>
> Keith: "Speaking." (That means, "The person you are already speaking to is Keith. I am Keith.")

Answer (score 2):

**This is Eva speaking** means **This person is Eva who is speaking**

Comment: Which would normally be phrased as "The person who is speaking is Eva".

Answer (score 1):

This is self-introduction:

```
My name is Eva.
```